# Assigning the result of an async function to a variable in a synchronous function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I have an async function:

```
async function GetCounterFromSharepoint() {
  let counter = await getSharepointListItems('mylist');

  console.log('Got counter from sharepoint as ' + (await counter[0].CurrentValue));

  return counter[0].CurrentValue;
}
```

The function works as expected, and the console.log statement prints `Got counter from sharepoint as 1500'`

I'm trying to call the function from the following function

```
function GetData(){

let initialValue = GetCounterFromSharepoint()
console.log('Value from SP is ' + initialValue);

/* some other lines*/

}
```

The console.log statement in this second function outputs `Value from SP is [object Promise]` and not the `1500` that i expect.

This second console.log statement is also printed before the one in the async function. So i thought if i add a delay before it, it would give it time to resolve. So i first tried:

**Using the `wait` function** from [developers.google.com](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/async-functions)

```
function wait(ms) {
  return new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, ms));
}

let initialValue = GetCounterFromSharepoint()
wait(2000) < -- /*added this */
console.log('Value from SP is ' + initialValue);
```

This had no effect. So I tried using `Promise.resolve` as follows:

**using Promise.resolve**

```
console.log('Value from SP is ' + Promise.resolve(initialValue));
```

This gave the same output of `Value from SP is [object Promise]`

**Using await**

```
let initialValue = await GetCounterFromSharepoint()
```

This gave an error: *use of reserved keyword 'await'*

What do i need to do to get this to work, please?

Comment: _"What do i need to do..."_ - Understand what `async`/`await` are/what they do.

Comment: This is simply not possible. If `GetData` calls an asynchronous function, that makes it asynchronous. Point. You should make `GetData` and `async function` that returns a promise so that you can use `await`.

Comment: @Bergi - Thank you! That did it, all I had to do was make my `GetData`  function async!

Comment: An `async` function always returns a Promise. If you write `return counter[0].CurrentValue`, this does not return a simple value, as you could expect, but a _promise_ of that simple value. This is why you see `Value from SP is [object Promise]`. Therefore you need to `await` it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `GetData` async

```
async function GetData() {
  let initialValue = await GetCounterFromSharepoint()
  console.log('Value from SP is ' + initialValue);
}
```